# Update an array in a pipeline

Tags: bash, shell

I want to update an array in a while. There is my code :

```
#!/bin/bash

LIST_OF_FILES=()
find . -name '*.[hc]' -print0 |
  while IFS= read -r -d '' file
  do
    # do some stuff
   
    # at the end
    LIST_OF_FILES+=("$file")
  done
echo "${LIST_OF_FILES[@]}"
```

But it does not work, my whellcheck gives me the error :

> Modification of LIST_OF_FILES is local (to subshell caused by pipeline)

How can I do to update my array `LIST_OF_FILES` ?

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024. It's good that you ran http://shellcheck.net on your code but if you had clicked on the error Id [SC2030](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2030) in the shellcheck output ("[SC2030](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2030) (info): Modification of LIST_OF_FILES is local (to subshell caused by pipeline).") it would also have explained the problem to you and told you the solution.

Comment: @EdMorton I have no access to internet with my working PC but I keep your link for the next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use process substitution instead of a pipe:

```
#!/bin/bash
LIST_OF_FILES=()
while IFS= read -r -d '' file
  do
    # do some stuff
   
    # at the end
    LIST_OF_FILES+=("$file")
  done < <(find . -name '*.[hc]' -print0)
echo "${LIST_OF_FILES[@]}"
```

That way, the assignment stays in the current shell.

Comment: Or in one go with Bash version >=4 `mapfile -d '' list_of_files < <(find . -name '*.[hc]' -print0)`